# Python Groupby and plotting of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi I have this dataframe as shown:

[image]

Is there a way to plot this ? For eg for 1-5-2021, to add up 10+7=17 for total . The graph need to show the daily statistics i.e.1-5-2021, the total is 17 and temperature is 36c.

sorry i forgot to add on..i want to show if there is a correlation btn temperature and total
Thanks!

Comment: You can just simply use df.groupby{'Date'].sum()["total"].plot(kind="bar")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a bar plot? then

Edit: thanks to **not_speshal** for pointing out temperature column

```
(df.assign(temp=lambda x: x["Temperature"].str.extract("(\d+)").astype(float))
.groupby("Date").agg({"Total":"sum","temp":"first"})[["Total","temp"]].plot(kind="bar"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#convert date column to datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d-%m-%Y")

#extract numbers from temperature column
df["Temperature"] = df["Temperature"].str.extract("(\d+)").astype(float)

#groupby to create the required plot data
df_plot = df.groupby("Date").agg({"Total": "sum", "Temperature": "first"})
df_plot.index = df_plot.index.date

#plot
>>> df_plot.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: upvoted! i missed the fact that op also wants the temperature

Comment: Thanks @Yefet ! We had very similar approaches to this though ;)

Comment: Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using pandas, the following can help you

```
pdf.groupby(['Date']).sum()[['Total']]
```

where pdf is the pandas dataframe containing the data. Then plot this into a graph.

Comment: Op said he wants a graph not display the dataframe